# How to find itunes cover flow view option

Tags: itunes

I'm a new mac user. i want to show my itunes songs view as a coverflow view. but i didn't find any options. i'm using Sierra 10.12.4.

Please don't give a down vote for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoverFlow is long-gone, from iTunes & the Finder too.

It was killed in iTunes 11 & also in El Capitan, OS 10.11

Ref: [CNet - 7 features Apple killed off in iTunes 11](https://www.cnet.com/uk/news/7-features-apple-killed-off-in-itunes-11/)